# Remapping issues. How do I map CtrlP to 'ff'

Tags: vim

Im trying to remap `:CtrlP` to `:ff` but I cant seem to get it to work.

Here is what I have tried:

`nnoremap ff :CtrlP<cr>`

`nnoremap <ff> :CtrlP<cr>`

Would appreciate the help!

---

To give more context, im trying to use the method :CtrlP when I open my project by doing: `vi .`. I am using Nerdtree as well.

Comment: `nnoremap` is specifically for normal mode.  `:ff` implies you want this to be something done in command mode

Comment: That said, if you are actually trying to do this in normal mode, your first attempt works on my machine.

Comment: When I use the first method, I get the error: Not an editor command

Comment: doesn't running `vim` with `vi` put it into vi compatibility mode disabling more vim-specific features?

Comment: Still a beginner with vim so not entirely sure what you mean lol. But I do have the line: `set nocompatible` within my vimrc

Comment: Running as vi doesn’t typically load the vimrc, does it? I would recommend just running as vim.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remap `:CtrlP` to `:ff`, because user-defined ex commands must start with a capital letter.  You could map it to `:Ff` by doing the following:

```
command! Ff CtrlP
```

If you want to map it as a normal mode command instead of an ex command, then the first choice you've mentioned should do it.

Comment: Adding `command! Ff CtrlP` into my `.vimrc` seems to be working but in your answer, you mention being able to execute in normal mode. I do want that but when I type: `noremap ff :CtrlP<cr>`, I get the error: `Not an editor command `

Comment: Both of them work fine for me.  What version of Vim are you using?  Did you maybe put a stray `<CR>` at the end of your `command!` ex command?

Comment: Version im using is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 19 2019 19:08:44)` and the exact line of code is: `nnoremap ff :CtrlP <cr>` which gives me the `Not an editor command`...

Comment: `noremap` is not a command. `nnoremap` and `nmap` are commands. `nnoremap ff :CtrlP <cr>` works (assuming `:CtrlP` exists). You never said what the rest of your error was (i.e. _what_ is not an editor command), so I'm just guessing.